# Detectar cambio en el <select> de datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables, materialize

Estoy tratando de integrar [datatables](https://datatables.net/) a un proyecto que tengo con [materialize](http://archives.materializecss.com/0.100.2/), sin embargo el diseño que poseen es bastante diferente al de [materialize](http://archives.materializecss.com/0.100.2/), investigando me encontré algunos ejemplos buenos pero con detalles, así que me puse a jugar con [datatables](https://datatables.net/) y [materialize](http://archives.materializecss.com/0.100.2/) por asi decirlo, por el momento esto es lo que he logrado: [ejemplo](https://codepen.io/Villatoro/pen/pLBEYO)

sin embargo en el incoveniente con el que me veo ahora es que en el `<select>` que poseen las [datatables](https://datatables.net/) para elegir cuantos registros quiere visualizar el usuario, los botones de la paginación vuelven a su estilo original, por lo que necesito detectar el cambio de `value` en el `<select>` para que cuando cambie de valor los botones tomen el estilo modificado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que el `input` de clase `select-dropdown` no está cambiando de valor ya que tiene la propiedad `readonly` a `true`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De ahí que no te esté entrando en el evento `change`. Cambiando el `change` a la clase `select-wrapper` (el `div` que contiene al `input`) funciona sin problemas:

```
$('.select-wrapper').on('change', function(){
        materialButtons();
    });
```

[Aquí](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KoYRYe) te dejo el ejemplo funcionando